# then Promise doesn't work

Tags: javascript, express, promise

i have this code for a statistic report over a db.

```
exports.calculate = function(req, res, next) {
    models.Quiz.count()
    .then(function(questions) {
        statistics.questions = questions;
        models.Comment.count().then(function(comments) {
            statistics.comments = comments;
            statistics.average_comments = (statistics.comments / statistics.questions).toFixed(2);
            models.Quiz.findAll({
                include:    [{model: models.Comment}]})
            .then(function(quizes) {
                for (index in quizes) {
                    if (quizes[index].Comment.length) {
                        statistics.commented_questions++;
                    } else {statistics.no_commented++;}
                };
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {next(error)})
    .finally(function() {next()});      
};
```

It works properly until the SQL statement, but  never makes the loop for, so i never can get

> statistics.commented_questions

or

> statistics.no_commented

Thank's in advanced!

Comment: Perhaps you're getting an error response from your `models.Quiz.findAll()` call?  If the code just stops at some point, then you likely have some sort of runtime error and you need to add enough debugging code to see where/what that error is.  You might also want to tag your question with something that would attract people who might actual know the APIs you are using since this issue could be specific to how you're using those APIs.  And, your title should probably be more specific to where your code fails (again to attract the right type of people who might be able to help).

Comment: thanks for your advice! and sorry for my english. next time i'll try to do it better.

Comment: My comments were about this question, not just for next time.  You can use the "edit" link to clarify or improve your question at any time.

Comment: You need to **`return`** the promises from your (callback) functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining promises together they need to know when the previous promise is either rejected or fulfilled. In your current code, the initial promise never returns a value/promise but instead calls an async function. The code essentially looks like this to the JS engine:

```
exports.calculate = function(req, res, next) {
  models.Quiz.count()
    .then(function(questions) {
      statistics.questions = questions;
      // ASYNC FUNCS THAT ARE NEVER RETURNED
      // ...
      // functions in JS without an explicit return statement return nothing (essentially `undefined`)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      next(error)
    })
    .finally(function() {
      next()
    });
};
```

So, after the engine waits for the initial promise to be fulfilled/rejected it fires off another promise for an async operation that returns a promise but doesn't return it to the original promise chain. By default the original promise chain receives `undefined` which is then passed on to the next method in the chain. In this case it would be the `finally` method.

You might wonder why the second promise is still updating the information if it's not waiting for it. This is a race condition and essentially that promise is winning.

To properly chain the promises together you need to return the new promise to the old promise chain like so:

```
exports.calculate = function(req, res, next) {
  models.Quiz.count().then(function(questions) {
    statistics.questions = questions;

    return models.Comment.count();
  }).then(function(comments) {
    statistics.comments = comments;
    statistics.average_comments = (statistics.comments / statistics.questions).toFixed(2);

    return models.Quiz.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: models.Comment
      }]
    });
  }).then(function(quizes) {
    for (index in quizes) {
      if (quizes[index].Comment.length) {
        statistics.commented_questions++;
      } else {
        statistics.no_commented++;
      }
    }
  }).catch(next).finally(next);
};
```

If you are using a version of Node/IO that has support for the native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object you can leverage that a bit to issue concurrent requests since none of them are dependent on each other. Note: the `Promise` API does not have a `finally()` method but we can use the second argument for `then()` to pass an error along.

```
exports.calculate = function(req, res, next) {
  Promise.all([
    models.Quiz.count(),
    models.Comment.count(),
    models.Quiz.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: models.Comment
      }]
    })
  ]).then(function(results)
    // `results` is an array of [questions, comments, quizes]
    statistics.questions = results[0];
    statistics.comments = results[1];
    statistics.average_comments = (statistics.comments / statistics.questions).toFixed(2);

    for (index in results[2]) {
      if (results[2][index].Comment.length) {
        statistics.commented_questions++;
      } else {
        statistics.no_commented++;
      }
    }
  }).then(next, next);
};
```

Comment: Sorry Jason, i've just release of your last code. Your solution is clever!! But now a new error occurred, Promise is undefined. Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: May be i need some declaration else at JSON?

Comment: @Jota As stated above `Promise` is only available in newer versions of Node.js or IO.js. If it's not available you can easily use Bluebird, Q, async, etc. to do something similar. Regarding your other question I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: the other question was about your 2nd proposes. In that case the app crashes when the Comment.length is read, and the error says "cannot read property of undefined" . In last instance I'll try to update the node version! Thank's!

Comment: @Jota Oh I see. That is due to the structure of `quizes`. Without knowing what the structure looks like I can't answer that question (which would be a different question). :)

Comment: thank's. I go to post another question about the new error. See you!